# Cocoa Singletons and Protocols

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, singleton, factory-pattern

I want to define a protocol and create an easy, standard way to grab a 'default', shared implementation of said protocol - singleton style. Cocoa adhere's to the following pattern:

```
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
```

but in both cases, they have @interfaces at the bottom of the object hierarchy. I'm struggling with how to do this using @protocols. I can obviously create a class that has empty or simple method implementations - but in reality, what I want is a @protocol at the bottom of the hierarchy. I've tried something like:

```
@protocol ConfigurationManager <NSObject>

//...

@interface ConfigurationManagerFactory : NSObject

+ (id<ConfigurationManager>)sharedConfiguration;

@end

// ...

id<ConfigurationManger> config = [ConfigurationManagerFactory sharedConfiguration];
[config ...];
```

and it works - but I'm always having to explain how to use this and why I did it this way. Is there a way to conform to Cocoa's syntax (calling convention) while still leveraging the value of @protocols?

As an aside, is there a reason why I wouldn't want to use @protocols like this? The implementing @interface can still leverage categories and alternate implementations, etc - just like how instantiating an NSString usually leaves you with a class extending NSString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea: create your protocol and a class with the same name with a factory method that returns you the *default* implementation of the protocol:

```
@protocol ConfigurationManager <NSObject> ...

@interface ConfigurationManager : NSObject <ConfigurationManager> 
+(ConfigurationManager *) defaultConfigurationManager;
...
```

Other specialized implementations can then inherit from your base class.

Comment: Ah - I thought that would create a name collision! I think that's just what I needed! TY.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of a protocol is that it specifies an interface *without* providing an implementation. If you want a default implementation, provide a class that implements your protocol, much as the NSObject class implements the NSObject protocol. Then clients can either subclass the class that you provide, or instantiate the class you provide and use the resulting object's implementation, as with your `config` object.

Comment: Absolutely, I want a protocol because I don't want to necessarily provide an implementation. What I ALSO need is a way to expose a default, simple or standard implementation as a singleton that is syntactically consistent with how Cocoa would do it (WWCD :) What I was missing was that the names could be identical. Your NSObject example hits the nail on the head - that is just what I was looking for! Jordão says it a little more directly but it gets me to the same spot.

Comment: Why a singleton? A singleton isn't just a shared object, it's a class that can be instantiated [no more than once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). From what I've read so far, you're really just looking for an easy way to create an object that implements your protocol. You can create a convenience method for that if you want, but creating a singleton seems unnecessary given what you've told us. I'm not convinced that you even need a shared object.